# Having trouble to build a package on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, build, terminal, cmake

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so apologies in case this is not the right place. Here is my question: 
I am trying to build [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim) github repository which is a Microsoft repository for simulating drones and cars. I am doing the build this package based on the instructions in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/blob/master/docs/build_linux.md) link. The problem is when I run the command `./setup.sh`, everything runs smoothly until it gets to `cmake --build .` where the command line stays there for around 1 hour and then throws some error here. Here is what the command line looks like from the time that I run `./setup.sh` to the end. Also, here is the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/blob/master/setup.sh) to the `./setup.sh`. My problem specifically is: Why `./setup.sh` does not work? I also posted this question on the github of the package.

```
Rouzbehs-MacBook-Pro-2:AirSim Rouzbeh$ ./setup.sh
+ set -e
+++ dirname ./setup.sh
++ cd .
++ pwd
+ SCRIPT_DIR=/Users/Rouzbeh/BoxSync/Fall2018/AirSim
+ pushd /Users/Rouzbeh/BoxSync/Fall2018/AirSim
+ downloadHighPolySuv=true
+ [[ '' == \-\-\n\o\-\f\u\l\l\-\p\o\l\y\-\c\a\r ]]
++ uname
+ '[' Darwin == Darwin ']'
+ [[ ! -z '' ]]
+ brew tap llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core, homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
convox                                           jenkins
brew install llvm-5.0
==> Installing llvm-5.0 from llvm-hs/llvm
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/llvm-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/cfe-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--clang--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/libcxx-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--libcxx--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/lld-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--lld--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/polly-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--polly--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/clang-tools-extra-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--clang-tools-extra--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/openmp-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--openmp--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/libcxx-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--libcxx--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/libunwind-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--libunwind--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> Downloading http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/compiler-rt-5.0.1.src.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Caches/Homebrew/llvm-5.0--compiler-rt--5.0.1.tar.xz
==> cmake /private/tmp/llvm-5.0-20180826-50196-5rhe1j/llvm-5.0.1.src -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DND
==> cmake --build .
Last 15 lines from /Users/Rouzbeh/Library/Logs/Homebrew/llvm-5.0/02.cmake:
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_stacktrace_printer.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_stoptheworld_mac.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_suppressions.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_symbolizer.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_symbolizer_libbacktrace.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_symbolizer_mac.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_symbolizer_win.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_tls_get_addr.cc.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_thread_registry.cc.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object lib/sanitizer_common/CMakeFiles/RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios.dir/sanitizer_win.cc.o
[ 95%] Built target RTSanitizerCommonNoTermination.ios
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt-stamps/compiler-rt-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [tools/clang/runtime/CMakeFiles/compiler-rt.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Any chance it's connected to this? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/6492

Comment: I followed the instructions in this link before and it didn't work out.